# Android Emulator does not launch LibGDX project?

Tags: android, android-emulator, libgdx

Whenever i try to execute the application on the emulator, the emulator displays an error saying "Unfortunately, My libGDX Game has stopped." The application runs fine in the desktop version though.

I have the latest nightly version, ADT version 18, latest GWT, and latest version of eclipse. My Android SDK tools is version 19, while my android SDK platform-tools is version 11.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I was following along this tutorial: [LibGDX tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=pOYrtJwYaGw#!)

Here is a screenshot of what i see: [image: Emulator Screenshot]

Logcat:

```
06-10 19:50:44.282: I/Process(1548): Sending signal. PID: 1548 SIG: 9
06-10 19:50:48.022: I/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-10 19:50:48.152: I/dalvikvm(1566): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-10 19:50:48.312: W/dalvikvm(1566): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication;
06-10 19:50:48.312: W/dalvikvm(1566): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/me/mygdxgame/MainActivity;)
06-10 19:50:48.322: D/AndroidRuntime(1566): Shutting down VM
06-10 19:50:48.332: W/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb40d5180)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx: findLibrary returned null
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:116)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:59)
06-10 19:50:48.392: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     ... 15 more
06-10 19:50:49.152: I/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-10 19:50:49.192: I/dalvikvm(1566): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-10 19:50:49.972: I/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-10 19:50:50.012: I/dalvikvm(1566): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-10 19:50:52.093: I/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-10 19:50:52.112: I/dalvikvm(1566): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If this is an ARM based emulator, you forgot to add the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders to your Android project's libs/ folder. Please follow the setup guide here: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew

I̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶x̶8̶6̶ ̶b̶a̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶e̶m̶u̶l̶a̶t̶o̶r̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶i̶'̶m̶ ̶a̶f̶r̶a̶i̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶s̶u̶e̶ ̶y̶e̶t̶.̶ ̶W̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶A̶n̶d̶r̶o̶i̶d̶ ̶x̶8̶6̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶

Edit.- x86 is now supported

Comment: Just to note that x86 are now supported as Mario shows in this post:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3103
"To use the x86 natives, simply copy the x86/ folder from the nightlies to your Android project’s libs/ folder (next to the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folder). The setup-ui will not add those libraries for you automatically. I opted to do it this way for the time being as x86 Android devices are super rare, and you’d just blow up the size of your APK unnecessarily."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... 
Try Android Studio -> Run -> Run 'android'. In my case it worked. 
If still fails I recommend to re-install libG

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work on the device either, try this:
android-project -> properties -> java Build Path -> Order and Export.
Then, click the project you've linked to (your plain java-project or desktop-project) and click the "Up"-button until it is at the very top. Make sure it's ticked [V].
I did that with the jars too, just in case, and now it runs on my device. I still get that same error on my x86 VM, because libgdx does not support x86 Android devices